# YouTube data api search - exclude live events

Tags: youtube

We are using an existing YouTube API before YouTube live events. Generally, our API query is as follows:

```
{https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?
 q=football+-soccer
 &orderby=published
 &start-index=11
 &max-results=10
 &v=2}
```

Is there any way I can filter out live events? I am unable to find any such filter.